# Is it normal for writing ~27k rows 38 cols of data to take ~6+ hours?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm creating a pandas dataframe of ~27k rows with 8 columns of text and 30 columns of floats. Pulling the data from Google BigQuery and creating the DataFrame and other formatting variables takes ~5 minutes. I run into a brick wall once I start the writing process though. It takes over 6 hours on average to write this data to a worksheet. It writes about 1.2 rows per second. Other excel templates I've made take at least 70x less time, writing 70-250+ rows per second. I don't understand why it's taking so long. Is there something I could be doing more efficiently?

I've tried using [Pandas' integration with xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) but I can't/don't know how to use cell-level formatting with it. Everything I've found seems to indicate that it doesn't support this. When I do use it, it takes all of 8 minutes to query, create, and write. How can adding cell-level formatting take so much more time?

I've also tried adding the `'constant_memory':True` option when creating the workbook lith negligible effect. I'm not sure what else there is to try. I've looked at the size of the data I'm accessing and it's ~24mb for the dataframe and like 0.6 for the format variable.

A minimal example of my writing function is:

```py
    num_rows, num_cols = main_df.shape

    for r in tqdm(xrange(num_rows), desc = 'Writing Rows'):            
        for c in xrange(num_cols):
            worksheet.write(r, c, main_df.iloc[r, c], excel_format_data[r][c])
```

I know [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) adds overhead but I use it with the other files I've talked about and they're much faster with the same code. The only difference is the number of rows but it doesn't scale 1-1.

I expect the output to take a while, maybe 2-3 hours based on other templates I've run. According to the [xlsxwriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html) it took them less than 30 seconds to write 12,800 rows with 50 columns of data. Their table shows time scaling relatively 1 to 1 with the number of rows so it should be taking me about a minute? It currently takes over 6 hours so something is clearly wrong.

I'm using a MacBook pro 2017 with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i5 and 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3.

Comment: No. But why are you writing data frame row-by-row?

Comment: Doing this: `main_df.iloc[r, c]` in a loop to access individual values **is extremely inefficient** and not the way you should be using `pandas`. `loc`/`iloc` based indexing is optimized for working with *lots and lots* of rows/columns. There is a lot of overhead because it aligns indices etc which is totally pointless for accessing individual values. Use `.iat` instead. Or avoid using pandas like this to begin with.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the built-in `df.to_excel` or `df.to_csv` methods and doing the formatting outside of pandas? If you need to format programatically, you could also separate the writing and the formatting by writing with `df.to_excel`, then re-opening and formatting separately with openpyxl

Comment: The xlsxwriter write part of your program shouldn’t  take anything close to that. I ran some test string and number data through an xlsxwriter test program and wrote 27000 rows x 38 columns in 35 seconds on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7. The call to `iloc` is more likely to be the issue.

Comment: @QuangHoang @sundance I'm writing the dataframe row-by-row and not using the built-in `df.to_excel` or `df.to_csv` in order to use xlsxwriter's `worksheet.write` method so that I can have cell-by-cell formatting. I have not found a way to write the data and still have cell-by-cell data formatting while using the built-in pandas methods.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @jmcnamara I didn't realize how inefficient `.iloc` was. Thanks for pointing me towards `.iat`. I've gotten a new error that I'm working out but it looks workable. 

@sundance Also thanks for pointing me towards openpyxl. If the `.iat` doesn't speed things up as much as I would like I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juanpa.arrivillaga has provided an answer in the comments that has helped me greatly (see above).

Basically, `.iloc` is incredibly inefficient and by using `.iat` instead I have been able to cut the write time from ~6 hours to ~7 minutes.